# How to make a shape change color when I click on it in a Connect Four board?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm writing a Connect Four game in Python using Tkinter. I'm now making a board. I want circles to change color when I click them.

Only the last column of the last row is changed wherever I click on the board. How can I make it so that whenever I click a specific circle, only that circle changes color?

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def conx_create_window():
    mw = Tk()
    mw.title("Connect Four Game")
    mw.geometry("650x600")
    mw.configure(bg="#3C3C3C", padx=50, pady=50)
    return mw

def main():
    m_window = conx_create_window()
    return m_window

m_window = main()
mframe = Frame(m_window, bg="#3C3C3C", padx=50, pady=150)
mframe.pack()
newframe = Frame(m_window, bg="#3C3C3C", padx=50, pady=50)
board = {}
buttons = {}
frames = {}
gameBoard = Frame(m_window)

#----------------------------------

def newgame_click():
    print("New game")
    mframe.pack_forget()
    boardOption()

def boardOption():
    newframe.pack()

def board7x6():
    gameBoard.pack()
    newframe.pack_forget()
    print("7x6 Board Size")
    for row in range(6):
        board[row] = {}
        frames[row] = Frame(gameBoard)
        frames[row].pack()
        for col in range(7):
            board[row][col] = 0
            frame = Frame(frames[row])
            frame.pack(side = LEFT)
            c = Canvas(frame, bg="#666", width=50, height=50)
            c.pack()
            r = c.create_rectangle((0, 0, 50, 50), fill="#3C3C3C")
            circle = c.create_oval(3, 3, 49, 49, fill="#3D3D3D")
            c.tag_bind(r, "<Button-1>", lambda event: print('works'))
            c.tag_bind(circle, "<Button-1>", lambda event: c.itemconfig(circle, fill="green"))
            print(" ", board[row][col], " ", end="")
        print()

def board8x7():
    gameBoard.pack()
    newframe.pack_forget()
    print("8x7 Board Size")
    for row in range(7): # 7 rows
        board[row] = {}
        buttons[row] = {}
        frames[row] = Frame(gameBoard)
        frames[row].pack()
        for col in range(8): # 8 columns
            board[row][col] = 0
            buttons[row][col] = Button(frames[row], text="", width=8, height=4, bg="#1EC811", bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
            print("     ", board[row][col], "     ", end="")
            buttons[row][col].pack(side=LEFT)
        print()

board7x6_btn = Button(newframe, text="7X6", bg="#64E545", command=board7x6, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
board8x7_btn = Button(newframe, text="8X7", bg="#64E545", command=board8x7, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)

board7x6_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10, ipadx=20, ipady=20)
board8x7_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=10, ipadx=20, ipady=20)

newgame_btn = Button(mframe, text="NEW GAME", bg="#64E545", command=newgame_click, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
load_btn = Button(mframe, text="LOAD", bg="#64E545", padx=25, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
ins_btn = Button(mframe, text="INSTRUCTIONS", bg="#64E545", bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
exit_btn = Button(mframe, text="EXIT", bg="#64E545", padx=10, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)#, command = exit_click)

newgame_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=20)
load_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, ipady=20)
ins_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, ipady=20)
exit_btn.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=20, ipady=20)

#----------------------------------

m_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It might be clearer for us (and yourself) if you use 'row' and 'col' variable names instead of i and j. Also some constants for MAX_ROW and MAX_COL instead of magic numbers 6 and 7. It's not immediately obvious which is which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `lambda` construction: c is always the same (last one) and is therefore not evaluated at execution:

```
c.tag_bind(circle, '<Button-1>',  lambda event: c.itemconfig(circle, fill = "green"))
```

Use a default argument instead::

```
c.tag_bind(circle, '<Button-1>',  lambda event, c=c: c.itemconfig(circle, fill = "green"))
```

So `c` is now a default argument and now you have different lamdas. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2731158/166605) for a far better explanation than mine.